# Testing multiple models in PyQt simultaneously; which one failed?

Tags: python, logging, pyqt, qabstractitemmodel

I happened to stumble across [Qt Model Testing](https://wiki.qt.io/Model_Test) earlier today, and realized this is exactly what is needed on a project which was grown in a very organic manner.

The idea is simple: implement a command-line flag that can be switched on in the future to run the program with the harmless consistency checks running in the background. Afterwards, start hunting down the problems one by one until the problems literally go away.

At its core, the basics of the first step seem easy enough:

```
self.mdlAlpha = alphaModel(self)
self.mdlBeta = betaModel(self)
# ...

# TODO: implement argument-switch toggle
from PyQt5.QtTest import QAbstractItemModelTester
QAbstractItemModelTester(self.mdlAlpha, QAbstractItemModelTester.FailureReportingMode.Warning, self)
QAbstractItemModelTester(self.mdlBeta, QAbstractItemModelTester.FailureReportingMode.Warning, self)
# ...
```

Within seconds, there were hundreds of (duplicate) errors that showed long before the program was in a usable state. Perfect! .... or is it?

It turns out that the reported errors aren't clear enough:

```
qt.modeltest: FAIL! flags == Qt::ItemIsDropEnabled || flags == 0 () returned FALSE (qabstractitemmodeltester.cpp:323)
qt.modeltest: FAIL! topLeft.isValid() () returned FALSE (qabstractitemmodeltester.cpp:753)
```

Sure, the failed tests are documented, but I have no clue *which* model is the buggy one due to the number of models being tested. (Commenting out all but one class at a time kind of defeats the point of having a command line flag to test everything...) I would really like to know which object / class is at fault and log that too, but I have no clue how to accomplish that.

Note that I have implemented a `QtMessageHandler` to convert Qt log messages into the programs logging messages, and I still want the failed tests to end up in that log file.

Comment: I can't see any obvious way to hack into `QAbstractItemModelTester`, and the qt message-handler won't provide useful context. A better solution might be to use [pytest-qt](https://pytest-qt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), which has a [pure python modeltester implementation](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-qt/blob/master/pytestqt/modeltest.py) that you can modify in whatever way you please. Recent versions also use the qt class by default (if it's available), but that can easily be switched off.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It doesn't seem useful unless I copy over the whole implementation as you suggest (due to print statements, fatal asserts, etc). I am not interested in 'taking ownership' of copy-pasted tests that are technically already shipped as a part of Qt; it would be better to just silently profit from any improvements made to the testcases made on Qt's end as new versions release. I wonder if it is hard to make some sort of proxy/wrapper model around my models that forward everything, and set an ugly constant I can rely on when catching the Qt warning later. Hmm.

Comment: No need to copy anything. Just use normal sub-classing and override the relevant methods. Asserts can be controlled with try/except.

Answer (score 0):

Naming your objects helps *some*. If you were to set up like so:

```py
self.mdlAlpha = alphaModel(self)
self.mdlAlpha.setObjectName("mdlAlpha")
self.mdlBeta = betaModel(self)
self.mdlBeta.setObjectName("mdlBeta")
```

before connecting the models to the QAbstractModelTester, then *some* of the output would include the object name. Not the lines you quoted, but at least the setup stuff where it goes to insert new data happened to show the destination model, though almost by accident:

```
qt.modeltest: rowsAboutToBeInserted start= 1 end= 1 parent= 
 QModelIndex(-1,-1,0x0,QObject(0x0)) parent data= "" current count of parent= 1 
 last before insertion= QModelIndex(0,0,0x0,FilesModel(0x55b37e4b88f0,
 name = "files.model")) QVariant(QString, "demo")
qt.modeltest: rowsAboutToBeInserted start= 1 end= 1 parent= 
 QModelIndex(-1,-1,0x0,QObject(0x0)) parent data= "" current count of parent= 1 
 last before insertion= QModelIndex(0,0,0x55b37e46ab90,
 FileFilterProxyModel(0x55b37e473b60, name = "files.sortfilterproxy"))
 QVariant(QString, "demo")
qt.modeltest: rowsInserted start= 1 end= 1 parent= QModelIndex(-1,-1,0x0,QObject(0x0))
 parent data= "" current count of parent= 2
qt.modeltest:     itemWasInserted: 1 QVariant(QString, "test")
qt.modeltest: rowsInserted start= 1 end= 1 parent= QModelIndex(-1,-1,0x0,QObject(0x0))
 parent data= "" current count of parent= 2
qt.modeltest:     itemWasInserted: 1 QVariant(QString, "test")
```

(I say that because, it's only the fact that it logged the placeholder for the row *before* my new one, that the model name was visible. Any log message that includes a valid `QModelIndex` shows the model name (if set), seems like — it's in the value of `index().model()`. However, *most* indexes **aren't** valid at the time the model tester is logging, so they still rarely show. Data that's being created logs with an invalid index, because the tester runs just before the actual insertion of the data into the model.

Still — YMMV, but I found that between the model names sometimes being logged, and being able to see the actual data involved in some of the other logs, I was able to follow which model/indexes were involved in any of the other messages in between.

Reading [the code of QAbstractModelTester itself](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/testlib/qabstractitemmodeltester.cpp) can also be enlightening. The "`flags == Qt::ItemIsDropEnabled || flags == 0 () returned FALSE` message includes a source file location, which is the line I've marked with a `<-- !!!` comment below:

```cpp
/*
    nonDestructiveBasicTest tries to call a number of the basic functions (not all)
    to make sure the model doesn't outright segfault, testing the functions that makes sense.
*/
void QAbstractItemModelTesterPrivate::nonDestructiveBasicTest()
{
    MODELTESTER_VERIFY(!model->buddy(QModelIndex()).isValid());
    model->canFetchMore(QModelIndex());
    MODELTESTER_VERIFY(model->columnCount(QModelIndex()) >= 0);
    fetchingMore = true;
    model->fetchMore(QModelIndex());
    fetchingMore = false;
    Qt::ItemFlags flags = model->flags(QModelIndex());
    MODELTESTER_VERIFY(flags == Qt::ItemIsDropEnabled || flags == 0);  // <--- !!!
    model->hasChildren(QModelIndex());
    const bool hasRow = model->hasIndex(0, 0);
```

Even though the message *doesn't*, the **source** makes it clear that it's testing whether a new, empty (therefore, invalid) `QModelIndex()` generated by the model has any flags it shouldn't (since it's invalid). Like me, you were probably returning a fixed set of flags from your `flags()` implementation, without checking whether the index requested was a valid one. Returning `Qt.ItemIsEnabled`, `Qt.ItemIsEditable`, and etc. for an **invalid** index is a model error, since there's no item referred to by that index.